# Is it possible to check values of headers using @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, httprequest

I would like to validate that the request received has some headers and that these headers follow some condition. I saw that I can use `@requestmapping` to check that all the headers are present like so:

```
@RequestMapping(method  = RequestMethod.POST,
            headers = {"PHS-DP-Created-Date","PHS-DP-Modified-Date","PHS-DP-Accessed-Date","PHS-DP-Revision"},
            value   = {"/{accountID}/{containerID}/{objectID:.+}"})
```

But I can't find a way to check there values against some condition (for example value > 0)

Is it at all possible using annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check only if particular header exist and if it's equal/not equal to a value. For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", headers = "my-header=my-value", method = RequestMethod.POST)
...
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", headers = "my-header!=my-value", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

You can't unfortunately check any additional conditions. To find out more about the details look at [HeadersRequestCondition](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/condition/HeadersRequestCondition.java) class.

The only option you have is to create custom [RequestMappingHandlerMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html) and change behavior how request is mapped to methods.